# Excluding a record in an Eloquent Datatables function

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, eloquent

have the following function which is called by Datatables:

```
public function data()
        {
            return Datatables::of (\App\places\Country::all() )->make(true);
        }
```

and I wish to exclude

```
where('id','<>',245)
```

but I seem to get errors whatever I do! Help appreciated!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't your where condition same as `where('id','=',245)` ?

Comment: No. I don;t want to show entry 245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use where with a != operator

```
Country::where('id','!=',245)->get();
```